# GDB: How to restrain the scope of convenience variable

Tags: gdb

So I have 2 custom commands:

```
define foo
  set $i = 10
end

define bar
  set $i = 100
  foo
  print $i   <=== print "10"
end
```

So $i is not scoped to each custom command which is what I want. Except using different names, any tricks out there?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of scope for convenience variables.  I don't know of a trick that would work in the general case, either.

The gdb CLI is rather limited.  If you have more complicated programming needs, I suggest using the Python scripting support.